# React + Browserify options for hot loading with multiple bundles

Tags: reactjs, browserify, react-hot-loader

Working on a project that uses Browserify and creates multiple bundles.  The only hot loading Browserify solutions I've seen don't support multiple bundles so I'm sort of stuck right now.  Unfortunately, switching to Webpack isn't an option for my client.  Anyone aware of any options I can do to handle this?